# How to give gradient to an object's transparency

Tags: modeling, node-editor

Below is an image of what I am trying to make :

[image]

I want to make a bottom of object start with red with no transparency,

and gradually shift towards no color with 100% transparency to the top.

Right now I was trying to play around with color ramp nodes on the object's BSDF, but cant figure out how for the transparency part.

Would there be other better ways to achieve this above effect?

Thank you all in advance!

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[image]

[image]

Getting math nodes also sort of ends up changing the whole object's transparency rather than only a tip, lmk if I made any mistakes for this method :)

Comment: I would use the Geometry node with Position for this in Cycles, but for EEVEE the gradient texture is likely your best option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how could I use the geometry node? I dont know where to start

Comment: Pretty simple. Use its position output, use vector transform to convert the position from global to local Object space, separate it into X Y and Z, use a map range to convert Z into the range you want, use that to drive a color ramp node, use the ramp’s output to drive the Alpha value of your material, make sure your alpha mode for the material is alpha hashed if you’re in EEVEE, and voilà.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this kind of setup:

[image]

don't forget to set blend mode to alpha blend or alpha hashed, if you are using EEVEE.

Works for EEVEE and Cycles.

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering :) but I have a problem, I have copied the nodes and played around with all the numbers within the nodes, but seems like transparency of the whole material changes only, and wont make that transparency gradient

Comment: I've updated and posted a pic of my shader editor in case you wanted to have a look

Comment: ok, please provide blend file, so i will check it out

Comment: sure, https://pasteall.org/blend/57f890b59ae847d9ba1dc6c4726cb468

Comment: first you did plugin from uv coordinate, not from object as i did. and second you had a scale z value in your mapping node of 0 instead of 1. So plugin from object and change scale z to 1 and it works. your material setup: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iac4p.png

Comment: in 2.9x it might be preferred to use a mapping node rather than the multiply add.  Setting From min/max to -1, 1 and To min/max to 1, 0 will avoid the error in your mulitply add node's math and might be easier to read.